# A number theoretic unlikely intersection phenomenon

Tags: nt.number-theory, lattices

Let $h_1, \cdots, h_k$ be co-prime integers, $k \geq 3$. Let $n$ be a square-free positive integer, understood to be extremely large compared to the $h_i$'s, and such that $\omega(n)$, the number of prime divisors of $n$, is much larger than $k$.

Let $T_k(n)$ be the set of pairs of integers $(u,v)$ such that $\max\{|u|, |v|\} \leq n^{1/k}$ and $\gcd(u,n) = \gcd(v,n) = 1$. For each $(u,v) \in T_k(n)$ let $x(u,v)$ be the unique integer in $[1,n)$ such that $x(u,v) \equiv uv^{-1} \pmod{n}$.

How many pairs $(u,v) \in T_k(n)$ are there with the property that there exists a tuple $(n_1, \cdots, n_k) \in \mathbb{N}^k$ such that $n = n_1 \cdots n_k$ for which $x(u,v) \equiv h_j \pmod{n_j}$ for $1 \leq j \leq k$?

I suspect that there should be a *uniform* bound to the above question, namely a bound which is independent of $n$ and the $h_j$'s (but possibly dependent on $k$).

To justify the title of the question, one can think of this as two conditions both giving rare lattices colliding. There are exactly $k^{\omega(n)}$ tuples $(n_1, \cdots, n_k)$ such that $n = n_1 \cdots n_k$, and for each such tuple one can produce an integer $s$ with the property that $s \equiv h_j \pmod{n_j}$ for $1 \leq j \leq k$. Each such $s$ gives rise to a lattice of determinant $n$, via $\Lambda(s) = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 : x \equiv sy \pmod{n}\}$. Now for each $(u,v) \in T_k(n)$ we see that $x(u,v)$ defines a lattice $\Lambda_{x(u,v)} = \{(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 : a \equiv x(u,v) b \pmod{n}\}$, and there are $O(n^{2/k})$ such lattices. Both types of lattices are rare, since there are $\gg n$ distinct lattices of determinant $n$. It stands to reason that lattices satisfying both conditions should be exceptionally rare.